# Mysql query insert into only if select count > n

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE id = 1
//if row == 1
INSERT INTO a VALUES(fielda) VALUES('value')
```

Is there a way to merge these two queries into one? I tried with 'IF (count> 0, ..)' and similar, but the query is incorrect.
This involves inserting a new record into the table, taking care not to exceed a pre-set number of records for each field.
In theory it should be similar to an INSERT IF ...

Edit:

@Barmar I tried but I think I did not understand what you wrote (in fact I made a mistake in the query), I try to answer like this:

```
THE QUERY AFTER YOUR RESPONSE:
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1 WHERE field1 = (SELECT id from a WHERE f = field2) HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 (all fields request) VALUES (all values request)

//field1 = id from table2
//field2 = id from another table: associative value

//ORIGINAL QUERY
//FIRST COUNT:
SELECT COUNT(*) from table1 WHERE field1 = (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE f = field2)
//AFTER THE INSERT:
INSERT INTO table1 (all fields request) VALUES (all values request)
```

I came to mind this example I try to show you:

TABLE PLAYER: fields(ID, TEAMID, NAME) => (id=int, teamid=int associate to table team, name=varchar)

TABLE TEAM: fields(ID NAME) => (id=int, name=varchar)

Suppose that the players in a team are maximum 20, so you expect maximum 20 records associated by the player table for the same teamid value, or at least this is what we humans think, because for the computer can also be infinite. I was looking for a way to allow the insertion only in the case in which it is actually permissible to insert records, in this case the condition is that in the players table there are less than 21 records per team.

Comment: What is `fielda`? Is it a column from the row in table `a` where `id = 1`?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're actually trying to do. Show an example of the original contents of the tables, and what you want to insert.

Comment: An `INSERT` statement either uses `VALUES` to list the values to be inserted, or `SELECT` to get the values from a query. You can't use both in the same insertion.

Comment: fielda (in the first example) is a common field of first table. you have right 
I was wrong to write: don't exist b, exist only a

Comment: Is there one table or two tables? The edit at the bottom has tables named `table1`, `table2` and `a`.

Comment: You're obviously having trouble describing this in words. Please post sample data.

Comment: Try to see the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT ... SELECT`, and put the condition in the `SELECT` query.

```
INSERT INTO player (teamid, name)
SELECT @teamid, @playername
FROM DUAL
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM player
        WHERE teamid = @teamid) < 20
```

`DUAL` is a dummy table when you need to select literal data, but need to include other clauses in the query.

Comment: Try to see the example

Comment: Will this work in race condition?

Comment: There's a transaction around the query, so it should.